# In what files are the stored passwords in Firefox saved?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I want to copy the files and folders which store the passwords saved from within Firefox.

Some sites claimed that they could be found here:

```
WindowsDrive/Users/UserName/Appdata/Roaming/Mozila/FireFox/Profiles
```

... and it seems like key3.db is the file where the password is saved; is that true?

If so, how can I these files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are my Firefox passwords saved?](https://superuser.com/questions/267005/where-are-my-firefox-passwords-saved)

Answer (score 0):

key3.db isn't the password file. It contains the key to encrypt and decrypt passwords. What you want is a file that is 8 digits long and ends in a .s such as 12345678.s. This is your password file.

NIRSOFT has a program called [PASSWORDFOX](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html) just for this purpose.

You could also migrate your password file to a new profile.

Create the new profile, visit a site where I have a password (using the new profile), enter the username/password, have SM save the password for me, then exit the program. Go to the profile directory where a XXXXXXX.s file will have been created. Copy the *.s (and *.w if it exists) from the old profile to the new one and rename it to the same 7 digit number as the new one (ie, rename old.s to new.s after moving the existing new.s out of the way).

Comment: Thanks alot but in the above directory which i told there is only these files: content-prefs.sqlite, cookies.sqlite, cookies.sqlite-shm, cookies.sqlite-wal, formhistory.sqlite, key3, permissions.sqlite, places.sqlite, places.sqlite-shm, places.sqlite-wal, signons.sqlite, webappsstore.sqlite, webappsstore.sqlite-shm and webappsstore.sqlite-wal. which is the correct file?am i go to the wrong directory?

Comment: G Koe, i copy those files i mentioned you in the last comment and i dont know how can i work with them because i want to use these copy of files to cget the passwords what should i do?