# Recover Firefox / Iceweasel password files from backup

Tags: linux, firefox, backup, passwords, password-management

I recently set my Firefox (actually Iceweasel 24.3.0) master password and promptly forgot it.

Before I set the master password I made a backup of my homedir and want to recover the password files from there. If all else fails I will make a complete recovery of the firefox directory which I assume will work. But I'd rather keep my history etc.

I read [Where are my Firefox passwords saved?](https://superuser.com/questions/267005/where-are-my-firefox-passwords-saved) and tried to restore only the files `key3.db`, `signons.sqlite` and `signons3.txt`. That prompted an error message that the Security System could not be started properly and no site could be opened. So currently I again have the locked files there.

Question is: What Files do I need to recover from my backup to reset the master password? If necessary what additional settings do I have to make for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not enough to copy the files, you also have to ensure that they have the correct permissions.

On linux it is `644` for the `signons.sqlite` and `600` for `key3.db`. `signons3.txt` isn't needed at all.

PS: Using a Password generation system that creates repeatably passwords from a given starting one helps prevent such situations. There is an App for Android (Master Password) that does that technically, but using a [manual approach](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2469971/endpoint-security/a-formula-approach-to-generating-passwords.html) will improve the situation too.